# Remote gem not installing into gemset with bundle

Tags: git, rvm, bundler, gemfile

I've forked a gem and updated it and am using it with my project. I've added the following line to my gemfile:

`gem 'pipedrive-ruby', :git => "git://github.com/biznickman/pipedrive-ruby"`

I then run `bundle install` and it outputs:

`Using pipedrive-ruby 0.3.4 from git://github.com/biznickman/pipedrive-ruby (at master)`

However when I run `gem list` for the current gemset the `pipedrive-ruby` gem is not listed. How do I get this gemfile to be included with the local gemset?

Answer (score 0):

`gem list` lists the gems installed in your system. When you use `gem 'foo', git: 'git://foo.bar/baz'`, the gem is installed in different place from system gems.

> Because RubyGems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in gem list. — http://bundler.io/v1.10/git.html

Instead, you can view the gems used by your project with `bundle list`.

You can find the location of the installed gem using [`bundle show`](http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_show.html) too:

```
bundle show pipedrive-ruby
```